# NLog proper way to show username in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, nlog

I'm using NLog and I'm getting the following:

```
[2021-10-06 11:52:51.1554] [INFO] [AccountController] admin Logged in. |user: notauth::
[2021-10-06 11:53:12.4143] [INFO] [UsersController] User info was changed for "Joe" |user: auth:ApplicationCookie:admin
[2021-10-06 11:53:19.8374] [INFO] [AccountController] admin Logged out. |user: auth:ApplicationCookie:admin
```

There are 2 issues:

Problem1: when I log who logged in, the user name is still not set.

Problem2: the username in the subsequent logs is shown with a prefix "auth:ApplicationCookie". I do not want that.
Here is my NLog.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">

    <targets>
        <target name="file" xsi:type="File" archiveFileName="${basedir}/Logs/Archive/nlog-{########}.log"
            archiveNumbering = "Date"  archiveDateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"
            maxArchiveFiles="30"  archiveEvery="Day"
            fileName="${basedir}/Logs/nlog.log"
            layout="[${longdate}] [${uppercase:${level}}] [${logger}] ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|user: ${identity}"
            concurrentWrites="false" keepFileOpen="false"/>
        <target name="console" xsi:type="ColoredConsole"
                layout="[${longdate}] [${uppercase:${level}}] [${logger:shortName=true}] ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" writeTo="console,file" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe try [${aspnet-user-identity}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetUserIdentity-layout-renderer) instead. See also https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers&search=package:nlog.web

Comment: Hi. I had tried that already. It shows nothing.

Comment: Then maybe [${windows-identity}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Windows-Identity-Layout-Renderer)

Comment: That's the user who is running iis, not the user who is logged in.

Comment: When using [${aspnet-user-identity}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetUserIdentity-layout-renderer). Did you remember to add the nuget-package NLog.Web ? And also added NLog.Web to `<extensions>` in NLog.config ? Maybe check the NLog InternalLogger for errors and warnings https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging